# Hive SQL - how to remove the max (date) from each person?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, partitioning

I'm struggling a bit write the most efficient way of writing sql query that is eliminating max(day) for each person. I tried `where where day < max(day)` but our hadoop environment doesnt allow that.

Essentially the goal is to select someone who had the same type of phone who switched over to the same vendor in the last 570 days.

Any suggestions to `table1` portion of the query?

````
with table2 as 
(select listener_id, device_id, max(day) day from 
devicetable b
where vendor_id = 42
and category = 'something' 
group by listener_id, device_id, day) -- max day for each person

,table1 as 
(select listener_id, device_id, ROW_NUMBER () over (PARTITION BY listener_id, device_id order by day desc) rowno from
    (select listener_id, device_id, day from devicetable
        where vendor_id=42 and category = 'something'
        group by listener_id, device_id, day)
where rowno <> 1)

insert into finaltable
select a.listener_id
from table1 a
left join 
table2 b
on a.listener_id = b.listener_id
where datediff (a.day, b.day) <=570 and a.day <= b.day -- setting the difference 
and a.device_id <> b.device_id
 and b.listener_id is not null; ```
````

Comment: I am really confused by your query.  Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your query has lots of logic that doesn't seem part of "getting everything but the most recent day per person".

Comment: @GordonLinoff - thanks for your comment. so what i'm trying to do is devicetable has a list of people, their device id, what vendor is their device, and date. 

the desired result i'm trying to get is people who stayed within the same vendor, but different device id( different type of phone) in the last 570 days. so the first part i did was what device they had in the max date, and the second part iam trying to do is removing the max date for each person but with the same vendor.
"getting everything but the most recent day per person" --> trying to do that in `table1` with `where rowno<>1`

Answer (score 0):

just a first suggetion for only a part of your code

If you want the max day   you should not mention day in group by

```
select listener_id, device_id, max(day) day 
from devicetable b
where vendor_id = 42
and category = 'something' 
group by listener_id, device_id
```

whether it refers to the database column or refers to the alias of the max

Comment: thanks so much! any thoughts to this part to get rid of max day for each person? 
`,table1 as 
(select listener_id, device_id, ROW_NUMBER () over (PARTITION BY listener_id, device_id order by day desc) rowno from
    (select listener_id, device_id, day from devicetable
        where vendor_id=42 and category = 'something'
        group by listener_id, device_id, day)
where rowno <> 1)`

Comment: I don't understand the goal of your code  so i can't help for the code in you comment 
 ...if you are able ..  a (simple) data sample and the expected  result could help  a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`SELECT listener_id, device_id, day FROM devicetable AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT listener_id, Max(Day) AS MaxDate FROM devicetable GROUP BY listener_id) AS B ON A.listener_id=B.listener_id AND A.day=B.MaxDate
WHERE B.listener_id IS NULL`

It will return all the rows excluding the ones with the max date for each listener.